# No programs/server/main.js file in Meteor build

Tags: meteor, build

I am trying to build a Meteor app using `meteor build --directory ../dist`. Everything seems to build fine, but when I follow the instructions provided in the generated README file I get an error saying the `server/main.js` file can't load. When I looked, I saw that the main.js file is not there.

Is there something I need to do before I build to ensure the file exists after build?

I'm having a very difficult time trying to build the Meteor app for a production serve, and I can't seem to find any clear instructions.  The Meteor doc instructions are very vague in regard to `build`.

Comment: Have you tried running `node main.js` from the bundle's root directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can see how the README can be confusing if not followed as intended.

The first command line states:

> $ (cd programs/server && npm install)

Note the parentheses.

Those cause the command to run in a subshell, which means that your shell will remain in the same directory after the command execution is done.

However, if you only execute the inner commands, you will end up in the `programs/server` directory and experience what you describe.

In any case, `$ node main.js` should be run from the bundle's root directory.

Comment: Thank you so much for clarifying that! I didn't realize the parenthesis were to be understood literally.